# Segmentation Fault using C macros

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, free

I have a curious issue while working with a slighty modified MobileC build.

I get a segmentation fault in a macro but when i put *printfs* in the code (its not possible to debug otherwise since it's interpeted C) I can't get the exact point where it happens.

This is the code:

```
...
printf("just to check there is no problem accessing "node" %d\n", node);\
printf("this will be printed\n"); \
node_type##_Destroy(node); \
printf("this will not be printed\n"); \
...
```

And the code of Destroy is the following:

```
int name##_Destroy( name##_p name ) \
{ \
printf("this will not be printed\n");    \
...
```

I have not modified this part of the code (except for the *printfs*) so I guess it's ok. Do you have any idea what can be happening here?

Comment: What happens when you step through the code with a debugger attached? What line does the segfault happen on?

Comment: The problem is that it's interpreted C so I can't debug it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. Now I know what happened.

Dietrich Epp, indeed *node* wasn't an *int* (I just wanted to know whether there was a problem accessing it since I was screwed up by the error and didn't have a clue about what was happening).
Thank you for warning me about C Macros. I've [read](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html) a bit about and finally I've figured out what was happening.

node_type type was *agent*. Therefore the macro expanded to agent_Destroy(node). The issue was that in *Mobile C* code there was a function than was named agent_Destroy(agent_p agent).
What happened was that both functions executed and the first one was the one defined directly in the code where there was a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 3):

There are two red flags in this code, but you haven't really shown us enough.

```
printf("just to check there is no problem accessing "node" %d\n", node);\
printf("this will be printed\n"); \
node_type##_Destroy(node); \
printf("this will not be printed\n"); \
```

This is clearly a macro, but it's a multi-statement macro.  This is the easiest way to screw up with macros, because it can be called like this:

```
#define MACRO() puts("A"); puts("B")
// prints "B"
if (0) MACRO();
```

Secondly, that string constant is very suspicious:

```
"just to check there is no problem accessing "node" %d\n", node
```

Notice how `node` is purportedly an `int`, but it appears between two string constants without a compilation error.  An `int` shouldn't be able to do that, so `node` is probably not quite an `int`.  It might be an entire expression, who knows?

Answer (score 0):

Segfault on delete almost always points to a corrupted heap.  Something has trashed the heap where your pointer lives (or where it is keeping track of prev/next pointers) and causing a jump to hyperspace.  Managed code makes this less likely, but it is still where I would start.